# Hat duplicates when info is expanded

Tags: bug, status-completed, winter-bash, winter-bash-2020

It seems like there is a bug that is causing a duplicate hat to appear when I expand info, like pressing "(more)" on a suggested edit. This bug does not seem to be specific to the suggested edits review queue though, as others have reported seeing this bug in other places, like code snippet expansion.

**Steps to repro:**

- Put on a hat.
- Navigate to one of your own suggested edits. (You can just also open the Suggested Edits review queue and go to a random suggestion, but there is no guarantee any of those users will be wearing a hat.)
- Click the "(more)" button to expand the top box.

**What should happen:**
Hat should shift down with the rest of the content.

**What happens:**
All the content shifts down, but a duplicate hat remains in the initial place.

**Before expansion:**
[image: Before expansion]

**After expansion with duplicate hat:**
[image: After expansion with duplicate hat]

Comment: similar, like this   bug also show many others area .also  it's work different way for different browsers.. example as a : Google Chrome Browser and firefox..here is similar [question link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358152/after-run-code-snippet-winter-hat-image-create-duplicate-image)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been fixed ([see here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/358561/51) for more info + haiku).

Answer (score 3):

I was visiting the [revision history of a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/333965/revisions) and noticed that the hats are not only offset vertically, but in this case also horizontally:

[image]

I assume this is caused by the same bug.