# If you run a code snippet, a hat still appears (hats are above snippets in the Z-order)

Tags: bug, design, winter-bash, stack-snippets, winter-bash-2020

If you run a code snippet, a hat still appears.

Steps to repro:

1. Go to a question where there is a snippet and where the OP wear a hat
   well, if you find that hard, just go here. [rowspan not changing color in ide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65301541/rowspan-not-changing-color-in-ide/65305244#65305244) (BTW, it's my answer)
2. Then, run the snippet.
3. [image]

Or just see here:

```html
Winter Bash 2020!
```

Comment: Same bug as reported previously: [Hat duplicates when info on a Suggested Edit is expanded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357935/hat-duplicates-when-info-on-a-suggested-edit-is-expanded)

Comment: I've updated my bug report ([Hat duplicates when info on a Suggested Edit is expanded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357935/hat-duplicates-when-info-on-a-suggested-edit-is-expanded)) to be more generic since this bug is not specific to the Suggested Edits review queue.