# Little bug in this year's Winter Bash presentation

Tags: bug, winter-bash

I found a little Winter Bash hat presentation bug (code name: TrumpHairLift).

Of a run of a code snippet, the hat of the answering user doubles and lifts off.

See this little animated GIF image I made from a screencast:

[image]

It was on [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65356037/476951) by Jamiec for the OP [How to filter in two deep arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65355681/how-to-filter-in-2-deep-arrays).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If you run a code snippet, a hat still appears (hats are above snippets in the Z-order)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357942/if-you-run-a-code-snippet-a-hat-still-appears-hats-are-above-snippets-in-the-z)

Comment: well, it's my question though

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of a duplicate