# After "run code snippet" winter hat image create duplicate image

Tags: support, bug, design, winter-bash, browsers

After "run code snippet" hat image created a duplicate image. This happens in my Google Chrome browser, but in Firefox it's okay...

[Bug link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65196929/how-will-i-target-the-nearest-child-element-aspect-of-on-click-area-in-vanilla-j/65322605?noredirect=1#comment115509448_65322605). Better see the picture:

[image]

Comment: but it's work different way for different bowsers...  Google Chrome Browser and firefox

Comment: it's probably a good idea to comment on https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/357935/369802 then, saying you can reproduce it on Chrome and not on Firefox. :)